# Why is my Placeholder not showing on my Tkinter Entry?

Tags: python, string, tkinter, attributes

I am working on an Entry, or Input if you please, in Python using a Library called **tkinter**

This is the code I have used:

```
entryvar = Entry(name).pack()
entryvar.insert(0,'Enter')
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

I am not sure why this is happening as i carefully followed a tutorial on this.

I have tried switching the single inverted commas to double inverted commas and then back, but that didn't work.
If you have any suggestions, It would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you wrote `entryvar = Entry(name).pack()`.  . `.pack()` returns as `None` so you should write:

```
entryvar = Entry(name)
entryvar.pack()
entryvar.insert(0,'Enter')
```

Comment: To be clear: `pack()` returns `None`, not `NoneType`